# Python, how to fill nulls in a data frame using a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, fillna

I have a dataframe `df`:

```
A     B      C
1     'x'    15.0
2     'y'    NA
3     'z'    25.0
```

And a dictionary `dc`:

```
dc = {'x':15,'y':35,'z':25}
```

I want to fill all nulls in column C of the dataframe using values of column B from the dictionary. So that my dataframe will become this:

```
A     B      C
1     'x'    15
2     'y'    35
3     'z'    25
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
dc = {'x':15,'y':35,'z':25}

df['C'] = df.C.fillna(df.B.map(dc))
df
#   A   B      C
#0  1   x   15.0
#1  2   y   35.0
#2  3   z   25.0
```

Comment: My favorite one

Answer (score 3):

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['C'].isnull(), df['B'].apply(lambda x: dc[x]), df['C'])
```